# Erro de compatibilidade

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet

Alguém sabe o motivo que dá esse erro de compatibilidade entre os navegadores e como resolver?
No chrome, mostra a página correta.
No firefox, a logo fica em cima dos nomes.
No IE, eu consegui resolver.
O problema esta apenas no firefox.
[image: Erros]

Comment: Poderia postar o código?

Comment: Pode ser display, position... coloca o link do site para analisar.

Comment: o código ta gigante até pq é pra uma loja,então acho que não caberia o codigo aqui. Ainda não está no ar o site. Está em construção, mas não dá pra colocar o site no ar com esse problema ai. Já revisei o código todo. Ja refiz ele e continua com esse bug.

Comment: consegui resolver o problema com o uso de background-image no lugar de background e o uso do clear na div da logo